# plug and play ExpressCard audio card on Ubuntu (how to avoid rebooting)

Tags: ubuntu, pulse-audio, expresscard

I got echo indigo djx expresscard as an audio card.

I use Ubuntu 10.10.

if I insert the card and reboot. it works.

if I just insert the card, it doesn't make sound. the blue led is on. I tried killing pulse audio but it restarts automatically and still no sound.

Comment: Sounds like a stupid simple thing, but did you reroute the output using `Sound Preferences`. It's probably not automatic...

Comment: yeah i did. if i boot without card it doesn't show up in sound pref. if i boot with the card then i take it out and put back in, then i see the card but it doesn't make sound. i would assume i should renew or reload expresscard but i'm not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a line

```
acpiphp
```

to

```
/etc/modules
```

and reboot the computer. plug and play will for for the expresscard.
source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/371434

Answer (score 0):

Do `lspci` to see if your device is even recognized by Ubuntu. If it is, try this:

Restart ALSA:

```
killall pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload

then you can try this to show what devices you have: aplay -l
```

Comment: i rebooted without the device and the device doesn't appear in lspci. i tried 'sudo modprobe snd-indigodjx' and nothing happened. even if i plug in the device, it doesn't show in dmesg. but everything works if i just restart